# Is it possible to combine multiple charts in one canvas in chartjs?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm new to chart.js, I want to implement multiple charts (each one contains 1 data series) in one canvas, they share the same xAxis, and share same tooltip (just like highcharts tooltip.shared), like this :

```
|-----------------|
|                 |
|      chart1     |
|                 |
|-----------------|
|                 |
|      chart2     |
|                 |
|-----------------|
|                 |
|      chart3     |
|                 |
|--------------——-|
```

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You cant put 2 charts in 1 canvas, what you can do is use 2 canvases and make 2 charts, disable the on canvas legend and use an HTML legend as demonstrated in this example (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/samples/legend/html.html). With the API's chart.js exposes you will then be able to hide and show your datasets of both charts